# on_message Cog triggers 2 bot replies

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a discord.py bot for random usage and i tried making my on_message event in a Cog for the first time, i've looked at different examples and i tried this:

```py
import discord

from discord.ext import commands


class AntiSpam(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):

        if len(message.content) > 350: # Anti-Spam for message lenght
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}, <a:cat_no:843799913958866955> You are **not** allowed to send unnecessarily long and annoying messages in this server!', delete_after=5)

        await self.client.process_commands(message)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(AntiSpam(client))
```

Now, everything worked perfectly until i tried using commands after that event was added, it replied with 2 answers , for example , i used a simple "hello" command  that would reply with `"{ctx.author.mention} World"` but , it would now reply with that message 2 times instead of one, i've seen a person ask someone if they had an `on_message` event, but that was never continued.
I also tried to shut down every python file i had running, killing the bot with `client.logout()` restarting my pc but still the same  error, any help?

Comment: I thing you can remove `await self.client.process_commands(message)` and it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not process commands in a listener, only in the event, simply remove the last line

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if len(message.content) > 350: # Anti-Spam for message lenght
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}, <a:cat_no:843799913958866955> You are **not** allowed to send unnecessarily long and annoying messages in this server!', delete_after=5)
```

You can have multiple listeners (decorated with either `commands.Cog.listener()` or `bot.listen()`) but only one event (decorated with `bot.event`)